# Python VS Code GoTo Definition does not work in Multi-root workspaces

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Is Code Navigation supported in Multi-root Workspaces? If I have a workspace that contains multiple repositories, Code Navigation only works on the first Repository I open.

I am unable to utilize code navigation for any other repository in my workspace. I have to exit VSCode and re-launch to get Code Navigation in a different repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/5132) in the Python extension.